# Apache Camel: wireTap and graceful shutdown

Tags: apache-camel

While I was debugging my Camel application I realized, that the graceful shutdown of a route ignores the outstanding tasks that have been triggered by `wireTap()`.

If I have a route definition like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .wireTap("bean:myWireTapBean")
    .to("mock:result");
```

and I set a debugging breakpoint in `myWireTapBean` (i.e. suspend the asynchronous processing of wireTap) then a `CamelContext.stopRoute(routeId)` call produces the following log messages:

```
11:36:12.352 [Thread-1] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.19.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
11:36:12.352 [Thread-1] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
11:36:12.352 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - ShutdownTask] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: direct://myRoute
11:36:12.352 [Thread-1] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
11:36:12.478 [Thread-1] WARN  o.a.c.impl.DefaultInflightRepository - Shutting down while there are still 1 inflight exchanges.
11:36:12.478 [Thread-1] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel  2.19.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 1.411 seconds
11:36:12.478 [Thread-1] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.19.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.126 seconds
```

Is there any way to prevent Camel from shutting down while there are still inflight exchanges in the `DefaultInflightRepository` that have been created by `wireTap`?
I've already read the [FAQ: How can I stop a route from a route](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html) but this doesn't seem to be an answer to this question.

Comment: You can use a direct route for the wiretap, then there is inflight messages on that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah the current implementation of WireTap does not take in account of active tasks if they are not being routed.

I logged a ticket to add support for deferring shutdown of the WireTap EIP if it has inflight tasks: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11539

The workaround is to create a route such as `direct` and then call that route where you can then call the `bean`, then when you shutdown Camel the `direct` route will have inflight exchanges and therefore wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultShutdownStrategy's default behavior is to complete route shutdowns, so it is one of those things where the default works for many scenarios, but not all and you are in the latter. If the exchange is run within a transaction, it would rollback, you might look at sourcing from a JMS queue or other so you can rollback and resume processing.

The Javadocs have good information on the behavior and various options you can use to configure the DefaultShutdownStrategy before considering writing a custom one:

[DefaultShutdownStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultShutdownStrategy.html)